# Definition of Artin map

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $L/K$ be an unramified Abelian extension. Then the Artin symbol $ \left ( (L/K) / \mathfrak p \right) $  is defined for all prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ of $\mathcal O_K$(because in an Abelian extension, the Artin symbol depends only on the underlying prime).

Now, pick a fractional ideal $\mathfrak a = \prod_{i=1}^r \mathfrak p_i^{r_i} $. Then we can define the Artin symbol $ \left ( (L/K) / \mathfrak a \right) $ to be the product:
$$ \left ( (L/K) / \mathfrak a \right) = \prod_{i=1}^r  \left ( (L/K) / \mathfrak p_i \right)^{r_i}  $$

Then the Artin map is defined as follows:

$$ \left( \frac{L/K}{ \cdot} \right) : I_K \to \text{Gal}(L/K) $$

**Question:** Why do we need the extension to be unramified ? Or in other words, if the extension $L/K$ is ramified, then the Artin map is not well-defined on all fractional ideals $I_K$ ?

It seems like I don't understand something either in the definition of the Artin map, or some basic fact about fractional ideals.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{p}$ is ramified, then its Artin symbol is not well-defined; it is a coset of the inertia group of $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @rogerl: Thank you for your reply! Could please give smoe more details? If $\mathfrak p$ is ramified then the Artin symbol why is not defined ?  Thank you and sorry if this a silly question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime lying over $\mathfrak{p}$, we get an exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
  0\to I\to D\to Gal(B/\mathfrak{P}\big/A/\mathfrak{p})\to 0,
\end{equation*}
where $D$ is the decomposition group (the stabilizer of $\mathfrak{P}$ in the Galois group), and $I$ is the kernel of the map, the inertia group.

If the residue field is finite, $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q$ for some rational prime $q$, so the Galois group on the right is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/f\mathbb{Z}$. The Frobenius element of that group is the automorphism $x\mapsto x^q$, which fixes $A/\mathfrak{p}$.

The Artin symbol is essentially a lifting of the Frobenius element. So if $I$ is nontrivial (which it turns out happens exactly if $\mathfrak{P}$ is ramified over $\mathfrak{p}$), this lift is defined only up to an $I$-coset.

If $I$ is trivial, then you potentially get a different lift for each prime $\mathfrak{P}$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$; it turns out that these lifts are in the same conjugacy class of $Gal(L/K)$. Thus if $Gal(L/K)$ is Abelian, as you point out, the lift depends only on $\mathfrak{p}$, not on $\mathfrak{P}$.

Comment: One last question related to the definition of the Artin symbol: In the case of $I$ being trivial, i.e $\mathfrak p$ is unramified in $B$. How can we conclude that the Artin symbol satisfies the condition $ ((L/K) / \mathfrak \beta ) (\alpha) \equiv \alpha ^(q) mod \mathfrak \beta $ for all $ \alpha \in \mathcal O_B$ ? And why is this unique ?  Thank's!

Comment: Because that is exactly how the Artin symbol is defined: it is an element that lifts $x\mapsto x^q$. It is unique because if $I$ is trivial, then $D\cong Gal(B/\mathfrak{P}\big/A/\mathfrak{p})$, so the lift is unique.

Comment: I understand everything now! Thank you very much for your answers and your time !